# Django Jquery sortable - how to access POST data

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

Nearly have this working but...

the javascript calls django like this:

```
.sortable({
        connectWith: '.object',
        update: function() {
                        var order = $(this).sortable('serialize');
                $.ajax({
                          type: "POST",
                          data: order,
                          url: "/focus_upd/"
                        });

         ....
```

And in the focus_upd function the data arrives ok

```
POST:<QueryDict: {u'task[]': [u'29', u'20', u'29', u'28']}>,
```

But if I refer to request.POST['task[]'] I get 28

Why is this happening and how can I get the whole list?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `request.POST.getlist('task[]')`

By the way, there's no need to use `[]` in field names in Django. This is a PHP idiom, and just makes life more complicated.

Comment: That's perfect.  The javascript is passing the post data it in like that.  Probably some way to change it, but it's working!
Thanks.